# Spacing between labels not updated when using sizetofit and landscape

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, autolayout

I have two `UILabel`'s separated by a spacer, expressed like this in visual format language.

```
@"V:[label1]-[label2]"
```

When label1's text changes i call:

```
[label1 sizeToFit];
```

In portrait mode label2 re-calculates it's constraint's like it's supposed to and moves up or down in relation to label1

In landscape mode however label2 is placed where is would be if the view was still in portrait.

Se screenshots here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1nh0qjrffx6gxdz/e_RQxdtbKn

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple causes for this:

1. It might depend on other constraints, that might be set through IB or code
2. You might have forgotten to call `updateConstraints` on the superview